# Pandas select rows where query is in column of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one column contains tuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2, 3], 'b':[(1,2), (3,4), (0,4)]})

   a       b
0  1  (1, 2)
1  2  (3, 4)
2  3  (0, 4)
```

I would like to select the rows where an element I provide is in the tuple.

For example, return rows where 4 is in a tuple, expect outcome would be:

```
   a       b
1  2  (3, 4)
2  3  (0, 4)
```

I have tried:

```
print(df[df['b'].isin([4])]
```

But this returns an empty dataframe:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `apply` with `in`:

```
print(df[df['b'].apply(lambda x: 4 in x)])
   a       b
1  2  (3, 4)
2  3  (0, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert tuples to sets and then find sets intersections:

```
In [27]: df[df['b'].map(set) & {4}]
Out[27]:
   a       b
1  2  (3, 4)
2  3  (0, 4)
```

it'll also work for **multiple** values - for example if you are looking for all rows where either `1` or `3` is in a tuple :

```
In [29]: df[df['b'].map(set) & {1, 3}]
Out[29]:
   a       b
0  1  (1, 2)
1  2  (3, 4)
```

Explanation:

```
In [30]: df['b'].map(set)
Out[30]:
0    {1, 2}
1    {3, 4}
2    {0, 4}
Name: b, dtype: object

In [31]: df['b'].map(set) & {1, 3}
Out[31]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```