# How to access to the element within a column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['a', 'b'], 1: ["('ex1', 'ex2')", "('ex3', 'ex4', 'ex5')" ]})

print(df)

    0   1
0   a   ('ex1', 'ex2')
1   b   ('ex3', 'ex4', 'ex5')
```

I would like to return the entry in column 0 when I find a matching string in column1.

For example, if I find 'ex4' in column 1, I would like to get the string 'b'.

I am trying to use a nested for loop to go through each row and then its own column.

However, how can I go through each entry within each column?

When I tried df.loc[row, column], I have the array (ex. df.loc[0,1] = ('ex 1', 'ex 2')).

But I do not know how to access to each element in that array.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always include your data in your question, and not as an image. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new here, and was not aware of this feature.

Comment: You're welcome. I think this question has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42674019/42346

Comment: Thank you again. I will check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another indexer. This example here will get you the first item in the 2 item tuple ('ex 1', 'ex 2').

```
print(df.loc[0,1][0])

ex 1
```